# Uncaught TypeError: this.removeBook is not a function at HTMLButtonElement.onclick

Tags: javascript, html

When I tried to call the `removeBook` method from the `createBook` method when the remove button is clicked, I keep getting the above error. I used `this.removeBook()` because of the scope level. Both methods are inside the class Library. For me to have access to the `removeBook` from inside the `createBook` method, I made use of the `this` keyword. But unfortunately, I keep getting the above error. If I remove the `this` keyword, `removeBook` is not defined as the error I get which I am very clear about the reason for that. But in this case, I cannot fathom out why this is not working.
Thanks for your help in advance

library.js

```
class Library { // eslint-disable-line no-unused-vars
  constructor() {
    this.books = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('books')) || [];
  }

  // Get books from array of objects
  getBooks = () => {
    this.books = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('books')) || [];
    return this.books;
  };

  createBook = ({ title, author, id }) => {
    const div = document.createElement('div');

    div.innerHTML = `
      <h3>${title}</h3>
      <h3>${author}</h3>
      <button class="delete btnDelete p-1 rounded" id="${id}" onclick="this.removeBook(this)">Remove</button>
      <hr>
      `;
    document.querySelector('.output').appendChild(div);
  };

  // Display all the books from the collection
  displayBooks = () => {
    this.books = this.getBooks();
    this.books.forEach(this.createBook);
  };

  // Add book to the array of book objects
  addBook = (title, author, id) => {
    this.books = this.getBooks();
    this.books.push({ title, author, id });
    localStorage.setItem('books', JSON.stringify(this.books));
    return { title, author, id };
  };

  // Clear all the input boxes
  resetForm = () => {
    titleInput.value = ''; // eslint-disable-line no-undef
    authorInput.value = ''; // eslint-disable-line no-undef
    titleInput.focus(); // eslint-disable-line no-undef
  };

  // Remove book from the collection
  removeBook = (elem) => {
    this.books = this.getBooks();
    this.books.forEach((book) => {
      if (book.id === elem.id) {
        this.books.splice(this.books.indexOf(book), 1);
      }
    });
    localStorage.setItem('books', JSON.stringify(this.books));
    elem.parentElement.remove();
  };
}
```

scrip.js

```
const library = new Library(); // eslint-disable-line no-undef

const form = document.querySelector('form');
const titleInput = form.title;
const authorInput = form.author;
const btnAdd = form.btn;

// Add event listener to the add button
btnAdd.addEventListener('click', (event) => {
  event.preventDefault();

  // Get the values of the input boxes and assign it to a variable
  const newBook = library.addBook(
    titleInput.value,
    authorInput.value,
    new Date().getTime().toString(),
  );

  library.createBook(newBook);
  library.resetForm();
});

library.displayBooks();
```

Comment: it is possible to share the form ?

Answer (score 0):

In the contest of the `onclick` at

```
<button class="delete btnDelete p-1 rounded" id="${id}" onclick="this.removeBook(this)">Remove</button>
```

`this` is the `button`'s element object. It does not have a `removeBook` method, because `removeBook` is a method of `Library`. Luckily, you have instantiated `Library` in the line of

```
const library = new Library(); // eslint-disable-line no-undef
```

So, change your `onclick` in the `button` as follows:

```
<button class="delete btnDelete p-1 rounded" id="${id}" onclick="library.removeBook(this)">Remove</button>
```

That will fix your current issue. You may have further issues down the line, but since you have not provided a reproducible example, it would be too much of an effort on my part to recostruct your structure in order to test, especially since the structure I would assume is highly probable to differ from your actual structure. So, if this answer does not solve the problems you face just yet, then you might want to edit your question and add an a minimal, reproducible version of your code.

Comment: Thanks, @Lajos Arpad. I later changed the createBook method to something like this and the problem was solved.

`createBook = ({ title, author, id }) => {
    const div = document.createElement('div');

    div.innerHTML = `
      <h3>${title}</h3>
      <h3>${author}</h3>
      <button class="delete btnDelete p-1 rounded" id="${id}">Remove</button>
      <hr>
      `;
    document.querySelector('.output').appendChild(div);
    document.getElementById(id).addEventListener('click', () => {
      this.removeBook(document.getElementById(id));
    });
  };
`

Comment: @AbdulghaniyyQoosim no problem. If this answer solved the problem you asked about in the question or provided you the information you needed, then you might want to accept it as the correct answer. If not, then you might want to write an answer yourself, in which you could explain the solution you have applied to help future visitors.

Comment: Thanks, @lajos, I resolved the issue with a lot of changes to the code thou.
I really appreciate your explanation and the time to make comment on my post.